# Does AWK understand number written in in E notation?

Tags: awk

I have a tab-separated file with several columns, where one column contains numbers written in a format like this

4.07794484177529E-293

I wonder if AWK understands this notation? I.e. I want to get only the lines where the numbers in that column are smaller than 0.1.

But I am not sure if AWK will understand what "4.07794484177529E-293" is - can it do arithmetic comparisons on this format?

Comment: Wouldn't it have been quicker to try it than to ask the question on SO?  You'd have learned more.  Commands like `awk` are seldom going to hurt you or your computer if you experiment with them.  The worst that can happen is that it injures your pride by saying "syntax error" or something similar.

Comment: To echo what Jonathan said: I used to be scared of exploratory learning too - that weird irrational fear of breaking something (even though that *rarely* happens), or having to struggle with not getting the correct results. But you just have to "dive into the cold waters" so to speak, and you'll find that it's really actually a lot of fun. You'll grow to voluntarily want to try to break things just to test your hypothesis of the situation, and that's really how you form mental models for understanding of new things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, to answer your question, `awk` does understand E notation.

You can confirm that by:

```
awk '{printf "%f\n", $1}' <<< "4.07794484177529E-3"
0.004078
```

In general, [awk uses double-precision floating-point numbers to represent all numeric values](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gawk/gawk_260.html). This gives you the range between `1.7E–308` and `1.7E+308` to work with, so you are okay with `4.07794484177529E-293`

Aside: you can specify how to format the print of floating point number with awk as follows:

```
awk '{printf "%5.8f\n", $1}' <<< "1.2345678901234556E+4"
12345.67890123
```

Explanation:

- `%5.8f` is what formats the float
- the `5` part before the `.` specifies how many digits to print before the decimal apoint
- the `8` part after the `.` specifies how many digits to print after the decimal point