# awk and numeric comparison with number less than 1.7e-308

Tags: awk, precision

The following command

```
echo 1.8e-308 | gawk '$1<0.05'
```

produce no output, while this one

```
gawk 'BEGIN{if(8.2547e-309<0.05){print "true"}}'
```

print "true".

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411597/does-awk-understand-number-written-in-in-e-notation#13411801) explain why the first command produce no otuput.

A possible workaround is

```
echo 1.8e-308 | awk '$1+0 < 0.05 {print}'
```

My question is: there is a better solution? For example some wrapper of awk that allow not to modify each script.

The optimal solution possibly would not require to recompile awk to use [mpfr](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/gnu-awk-41-teaching-old-bird-some-new-tricks-part-ii) library.

Comment: 2.226e-308 is the minimum value recogninzed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
echo 1.8e-308 | gawk '($1+0)<0.05'
```

produces:

```
1.8e-308
```

---

Some other interesting observations:

```
echo "True" | gawk '1.8e-308<0.05'
```

gives

```
True
```

and

```
echo "True" | gawk '1.8e-322<1.9e-322'
```

gives

```
True
```

whereas

```
echo "True" | gawk '1.8e-323<1.9e-323'
```

gives nothing..

Comment: I edited my question to take into account your solution just when you edited your answer! :)

Comment: @mox Ok, no problem :)

Comment: and to address the original question: no, there is no better solution.

Comment: @EdMorton But I wonder, what happens here actually? Is it like: when awk sees the value `1.8e-308` it replaces it with a string such that when you add the number zero to that value (a string) it becomes then the numerical value of zero?

Comment: @HåkonHægland - all input values and variables in awk have the same type which is "numeric string" and it's when they are first used in the script that they take on a specific type of "number" or "string" based on some internal rules awk uses to make it's best guess. So, when you write "$1 < 0.5" awk has to decide what type $1 is and if it should be doing a numeric or string comparison. If you specifically NEED one or the other then you must either perform an artihmetic operation on it to tell awk it's numeric (e.g. add 0) or concatenate with the null string (`""`) to tell awk it's a string.

Answer (score 0):

just beware of these nuiances : (`[X]` := `TRUE`)

```
      ($1 < "-3") (+$1 < "-3") ($1 < -3) ($1 < -3 "") ($1 < __)
```

---

```
-4            .          .         [X]         .         [X]
.4e1          .          .          .          .          . 
 4.           .          .          .          .          . 
 40e-1        .          .          .          .          .
```

---

```
 4            .          .          .          .          . 
+4           [X]         .          .         [X]         . 
-2           [X]        [X]         .         [X]         . 
-2v          [X]        [X]        [X]        [X]        [X]
```

*variable* `__` *is set by command line assignment*

> ```
> awk '...' __='-3'
> ```

Some of it has to do with the strange decision for `ASCII` to place `+` at a lower ordinal value than `-`, making