# seeking a consistent transfer of scientific notation to normal notation in awk (or using some other Linux utility)

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Please can you indicate how I can instead of:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print 8.54585e+09}'
8.54585e+09
awk 'BEGIN{print 8.54585e+08}'
854585000
```

get the desired printout

```
awk 'BEGIN{print 8.54585e+09}'
8545850000
awk 'BEGIN{print 8.54585e+08}'
854585000
```

I.e. I need a general and robust way to transfer scientific notation in the normal notation. I am not bound to 'awk', and any other core Linux utility would be also fine.

Edit: The previous post [Does AWK understand number written in in E notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411597/does-awk-understand-number-written-in-in-e-notation) doesn't answer my question. I do not question if 'awk' can understand scientific notation (clearly it does!), I am seeking a robust way to transfer scientific notation in the normal notation.

What do I have to change in awk so that the printout of 8.54585e+09 and 8.54585e+08 is both converted in the normal notation?

Thanks!

Comment: That linked post also shows how to use `printf` instead of `print`, the former allowing precise [configuration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) of the output format. (While somewhat confusing at first, it is not uncommon to close a question as duplicate of another, somewhat different question, as long as the top *answers* apply to your problem as well. So it is not so much a "your question is a duplicate", as "an answer to this question would be a duplicate to the answers to that other question".)

Comment: Thanks for further clarification! Just for general knowledge, can somebody nevertheless please clarify why 8.54585e+09 and 8.54585e+08 are converted inconsistently into the standard notation in awk?

Comment: Actually I am unable to reproduce the described behavior; I am getting "normal" notation for either case. But that may be just me running Ubuntu under WSL.

Comment: I see this problem both on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and Debian 10, using mawk 1.3.3

Comment: The problem is NOT present in GNU Awk 4.2.1: awk 'BEGIN{print 8.54585e+09}' prints nicely 8545850000 . So it's mawk internal incosistency, not awk

Answer (score 1):

[`OFMT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/OFMT.html) built-in variable dictates how numbers are `print`ed in GNU `AWK`, please try setting in to `%.0f` if you wish to have all numbers printed as integers (rounded) that is

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFMT="%.0f";print 8.54585e+09}'
```

and write if it does what you want.

*(I tested in gawk 4.2.1 and got `8545850000` with and without setting OFMT, I do not know how it would interact with your AWK)*

Comment: Thanks! Your solution, however, works only for integers: ```$ awk 'BEGIN{print 8.54585e+09}'
8.54585e+09``` and ```$ awk 'BEGIN{OFMT="%.0f";print 8.54585e+09}'
8545850000```

Comment: But it generates then another problem: ```$ awk 'BEGIN{OFMT="%.0f";print 8.54585e+02}'
855```

Comment: @user9751447 it was unclear from your sample data that you would want also work with values not being multiples of `1`. In this case you might use `OFMT` to set how many digits after `.` would be shown, for example `%.6f` will cause 6 digits to appear so for `8.54585e+02` you will get `854.585000`

Comment: Thanks! After some thought, I think ideally this shall be handled by Bash itself internally, in a sense that if integer is written in a scientific notions using 'e' and 'E', it shall be interpreted as an integer. I posted also on the Bash malilng list, let's see what happens there. It's simply too much of an overhead to check for each external command if a large integer was written or not using sci. notation.

Comment: @user9751447: Bash has no own concept of floating point numbers or notation. Its integers are also limited to what the platform can represent (32 or 64 bit), and these are traditionally expressed as plain numbers. Since there are tools that bash can call that can handle floating point numbers just fine (`bc` for example), and bash has no need for exponential notation of its own, I would not expect anything to come off your mail to their mailing list. It also remains somewhat unclear what you are *actually* trying to do here.

Comment: I am very well aware that Bash doesn't support floating-point arithmetic, but that's not really the point here. As a matter of fact, ```bc``` does support floating-point arithmetic, but sadly not 'e' and 'E' sci. notation. One of my Bash scripts using 'awk' failed after I ported it to another machine, because on one machine awk was soft-linked to mawk and on another to gawk, and they format differently the following: ```awk 'BEGIN{print 8.54585e+09}'``` . After discussion on Bash mailing list, it seems best to extend the existing utility ```numfmt```, to handle also 'e' and 'E' notation.